# npm start error:npm start require(...) is not a function npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE

Tags: reactjs, npm-start

Just start to learn react js and finished some pages, but there is an error when I run "npm start" today. I do not change anything since last time...
Anyone can help me out? Thank you.

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: "but there is an error when I run `npm start` today. I do not change anything since last time..."      Was `npm start` working at least yesterday?

Comment: yes, it worked this morning....

Comment: Ok then can I check your package.json please? And let me know which package did you install latest from when it was working. thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Thank you everyone, at last I delete the setupProxy.js file in the src folder, then npm start works.

Comment: Glad to hear that. except for setupProxy.js included, usually remove node_module, and clear cache then npm start works. I have many experience of fixing this weird issues. :)

Answer (score 0):

Please try this one.

1. Delete nodes_modules
2. `npm install -g npm`
3. `npm install & npm install -D`
4. `npm run start`

Comment: Have tried, but still have the same error.. Thank you

Answer (score 0):

It seems like you don't have react-scripts in your global environment.try this:

```
npm install -g react-scripts
```

or

```
npm install --save react react-dom react-scripts
```

If above doesn't work try this

1. **Delete npm and npm-cache** directories... (don't worry you can install npm globally later)
2. Go back to your application directory and remove `node_modules` folder
3. Now enter `npm install` to install the dependencies (delete package-lock.json if it's already created)
4. Now run `npm install --save react react-dom react-scripts`
5. Get it started with   `npm start`

Comment: Have tried, but still have the same error..  Thank you